# A question for a conditional probability exercise

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given this question

> Suppose urn #1 has 3 red and 2 blue balls, and urn #2 has 4 red and 7
> blue balls. Suppose one of the two urns is selected with probability
> 1/2 each, and then one of the balls within that urn is picked
> uniformly at random. What is the probability that urn #2 is selected
> at the first stage (event A) and a blue ball is selected at the second
> stage (event B)?

And according to this [book, Page 22 (Page 35 in PDF)](https://www.utstat.toronto.edu/mikevans/jeffrosenthal/book.pdf), **P(B | A)** is $\dfrac{7}{11}$

Why is it just $\dfrac{7}{11}$?

I understand it is because there is 4+7 balls in total and 7 of them are blue but I don't understand why it is not necessary to consider urn #1(the **A** part), that is, why not
$\dfrac{7}{11}$ + $\dfrac{2}{5}$ or something to do with **A**

Comment: We are assuming that $A$ has already occurred so we don't have to consider that half of the time the other urn will be selected.

Comment: Is there a formula or mathmatical way to the express the idea of coming up 7/11?
I guess writing down **P(B|A) = 7/11(assuming A has already occured)** is not methodological enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(B|A)$ is the probability of the occurrence of event $B$ given that event $A$ has already taken place. So, you know that urn 2 has been chosen. Hence,
$$P(B|A)=P(\text{blue ball is picked from urn 2})=\frac{7}{11}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I do understand the formula and I can apply it without problem. However, I am confused with this particular example, specifically how to come up the value of P(B | A)

Comment: Oh thanks, now I see it now.

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad that you strived towards mathematical clarity.

Comment: I have myself confused after re-reading it. **P(B∩A)=P(A)×P(B)** is only true if A and B are independent and I don't believe they are in this case. Now I cannot see how you come up with **P(B∩A)=P(A)×P(B)** if the events are not independent.

Comment: You are right. My definition of event B was incorrect. My bad. It should be fine now.

Comment: You are asked for the joint probability. So you can't  directly use the definition to find conditional probability without first finding the joint probability.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.